# My android app crash due to Java.lang.RuntimeException

Tags: java, android, exception, runtime, lang

When I run this on my emulator or real device above android version 7, it works really fine. However,The problem starts when i tried to install it on `android` version 6 or 5 and below even though my minimum `SDK` is 4.0.1. or 15.

Last two days tried to solved it by going through different post of stackoverflow, but noting worked properly.

Here is my crash-Stack Tarces log

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: 
     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity 
    (ActivityThread.java:2534)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity 
     (ActivityThread.java:2608)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800 (ActivityThread.java:178)
     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:1470)
     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:111)
     at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:194)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:5637)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:372)
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run 
     (ZygoteInit.java:959)
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:754)

Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: 
     at android.app.ActivityManager$TaskDescription.<init> 
     (ActivityManager.java:555)
     at android.app.Activity.onApplyThemeResource (Activity.java:3741)
     at android.view.ContextThemeWrapper.initializeTheme 
     (ContextThemeWrapper.java:140)
     at android.view.ContextThemeWrapper.setTheme 
     (ContextThemeWrapper.java:85)
     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setTheme 
     (AppCompatActivity.java)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity 
     (ActivityThread.java:2474)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity 
     (ActivityThread.java:2608)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800 (ActivityThread.java:178)
     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:1470)
     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:111)
     at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:194)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:5637)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:372)
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run 
     (ZygoteInit.java:959)
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:754)
```

android manifests

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>

<application 
   android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/iconlarge"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@drawable/iconlarge"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".dropdown.AboutUs"></activity>
    <activity android:name=".Activity.MainActivity">

     <intent-filter>
       [![enter image description here][1]][1]<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".viewClass" />
    />

    <activity android:name=".webview.seetings.PrivacyPolicy" />
    <activity android:name=".webview.seetings.TermsCondition" />
    <activity android:name=".infozone" />
    <activity android:name=".webview.timeadjust" />

</application>
```

Here is my Style.xml resource:

```
 <resources>

<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/transparent</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/black</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" 
parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

<style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" 
parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"/>

<style name="TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Title"
    parent="@android:style/TextAppearance">
    <item name="android:textSize">20sp</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/black</item>
</style>
```

Main Activity Layout

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp">


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="4dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="1dp"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/Land1"
                android:layout_margin="14dp"
                android:text="@string/LandTime"
                android:textAllCaps="false"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textSize="15sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textColor="@color/liteblue"
                android:background="@drawable/border"
                android:padding="10dp"
                />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/Land2"
                android:layout_margin="14dp"
                android:text="@string/LandDua"
                android:textAllCaps="false"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textSize="15sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textColor="@color/liteblue"
                android:background="@drawable/border"
                android:padding="10dp"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/Land3"
                android:layout_margin="14dp"
                android:text="@string/LandOju"
                android:textAllCaps="false"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textSize="15sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textColor="@color/liteblue"
                android:background="@drawable/border"
                android:padding="10dp"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/Land4"
                android:layout_margin="14dp"
                android:text="@string/LandKoron"
                android:textAllCaps="false"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textSize="15sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textColor="@color/liteblue"
                android:background="@drawable/border"
                android:padding="10dp"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/Land5"
                android:layout_margin="14dp"
                android:text="@string/LandHadis"
                android:textAllCaps="false"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textSize="15sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textColor="@color/liteblue"
                android:background="@drawable/border"
                android:padding="10dp"/>

        </LinearLayout>


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="9"
            >




            <Button
                android:id="@+id/share"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
                android:layout_weight="3"
                android:background="@color/coloraqua"
                android:drawableLeft="@drawable/share"
                android:text="Share"
                android:textAllCaps="false"
                />


            <Button
                android:id="@+id/rate"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
                android:layout_weight="3"
                android:background="@color/coloraqua"
                android:drawableLeft="@drawable/rating"
                android:shadowColor="@color/colorAccent"
                android:text="Rate"
                android:textAllCaps="false" />
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/info"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
                android:layout_weight="3"
                android:background="@color/coloraqua"
                android:drawableLeft="@drawable/infoa"
                android:text="Info"
                android:textAllCaps="false" />


        </LinearLayout>


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="9">











        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

        <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
            xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:id="@+id/adView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            ads:adSize="BANNER"
            ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-2863417604404784/6151426605">
        </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>




    </RelativeLayout>


</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

View class for recycler Adapter

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="15dp"
    android:background="@drawable/border"

    >




    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:background="@color/white"
        >


            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="ddddddddd"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:id="@+id/title"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:textColor="@color/black"/>

    </LinearLayout>





    </RelativeLayout>
```

viewclass for recycler adapter

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/recycle"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        >

    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
            xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:id="@+id/adView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"

            ads:adSize="BANNER"
            ads:adUnitId="@string/banner">
        </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>




    </RelativeLayout>
```

webview layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
 android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
 android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
 android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
  tools:context=".Activity.MainActivity">

 <LinearLayout
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:layout_marginBottom="58dp">

  <WebView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/webView"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
   </LinearLayout>


   <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"

    ads:adSize="BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="@string/O3">
 </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

one additional error log

```
 1. java.lang.RuntimeException: 
 2.   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:2534)
 3.   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:2608)
 4. at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800 (ActivityThread.java:178)
 5. at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:1470)
 6. at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:111)
 7. at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:194)
 8. at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:5637)
 9. at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)
11. at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:372)
12. at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:959)
 13. at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:754)

 Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: 
  14. at android.app.ActivityManager$TaskDescription.<init> (ActivityManager.java:555)
  15.  at android.app.Activity.onApplyThemeResource (Activity.java:3741)
  16. at android.view.ContextThemeWrapper.initializeTheme (ContextThemeWrapper.java:140)
  17.  at android.view.ContextThemeWrapper.setTheme (ContextThemeWrapper.java:85)
  18. at a.b.h.a.m.setTheme(:0)
  19. at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:2474)
```

Comment: please post your xml layout file

Comment: added all my xml layout for your reference

Comment: On your webview layout it seems you defined string value as “03”. It seems to be a problem. You cannot define variable name starting with number. Please change its name and share the result. If it is not the solution for your problem.

Comment: this string value for Adview,and its Text string which contains value of admob's app id, before paste it here, i might have changed .                                  
       actual code like below:                                               
         **ads:adSize="BANNER"**
        **ads:adUnitId="@string/Oj3">**
    **</com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>"**

Comment: Did you extend AppcompatActivity or just Activity. If it is AppCompatActivity change it to Activity and  check if you are getting error if you don get any errroy, issue might be your theme customization. I did get some error once look likes this issue.

Comment: i have tried that , did not work. I also think, Its due to theme. Above, I have added another log under **one additional error log**, where it shows setTheme(:0), **line number 19**. But looking at my **style.xml** file, could not figure out the issue.